# C++, fast remove elements from vector unique to another vector

Tags: c++, vector, unique

There are 2 unsorted vectors of int and vector of pairs int, int

```
std::vector <int> v1;
std::vector <std::pair<int, float> > v2;
```

containing millions of items.

How to remove as fast as possible such items from v1, that are unique to v2.first (ie not included in v2.first)?

Example:

```
v1:  5 3 2 4 7 8
v2: {2,8} {7,10} {5,0} {8,9}
----------------------------
v1: 3 4
```

Comment: Is sorting one of the vectors an option or they must remain in that order?

Comment: Is either v1 or v2 much bigger than the other?

Comment: @ Rob: they are approximately of the same length (+-30%).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two tricks I would use to do this as quickly as possible:

1. Use some sort of associative container (probably `std::unordered_set`) to store all of the integers in the second vector to make it dramatically more efficient to look up whether some integer in the first vector should be removed.
2. Optimize the way in which you delete elements from the initial vector.

More concretely, I'd do the following.  Begin by creating a `std::unordered_set` and adding all of the integers that are the first integer in the pair from the second vector.  This gives (expected) O(1) lookup time to check whether or not a specific `int` exists in the set.

Now that you've done that, use the `std::remove_if` algorithm to delete everything from the original `vector` that exists in the hash table.  You can use a lambda to do this:

```
std::unordered_set<int> toRemove = /* ... */
v1.erase(std::remove_if(v1.begin(), v1.end(), [&toRemove] (int x) -> bool {
    return toRemove.find(x) != toRemove.end();
}, v1.end());
```

This first step of storing everything in the `unordered_set` takes expected O(n) time.  The second step does a total of expected O(n) work by bunching all the deletes up to the end and making lookups take small time.  This gives a total of expected O(n)-time, O(n) space for the entire process.

If you are allowed to sort the second vector (the pairs), then you could alternatively do this in O(n log n) worst-case time, O(log n) worst-case space by sorting the vector by the key, then using `std::binary_search` to check whether a particular `int` from the first `vector` should be eliminated or not.  Each binary search takes O(log n) time, so the total time required is O(n log n) for the sorting, O(log n) time per element in the first vector (for a total of O(n log n)), and O(n) time for the deletion, giving a total of O(n log n).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Isn't your algorithm just a big description of [`std::remove_if()`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/remove_if.html)?

Comment: @AndreCaron- Ah, yes it is.  The complexity of getting remove_if to remove things that are stored in a hash table used to be insane because there weren't lambdas, but now that there are that's *by far* a better way to do this.  Let me make a note of that...

Comment: @ templatetypedef Very interesting solution with a deep explanations, thanks. But I do not have any experience with lambda expressions. Is there a compiler support for lambda expressions in VS 2010? Could I ask you for a code sample?

Comment: @ templatetypedef Is there any solution without lambda expressions?

Comment: @justik: yes, use a function object.  It's semantically exactly equivalent, just a bit longer to type.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that neither container is sorted and that sorting is actually too expensive or memory is scarce:

```
v1.erase(std::remove_if(v1.begin(), v1.end(), 
                        [&v2](int i) { 
                         return std::find_if(v2.begin(), v2.end(), 
                                             [](const std::pair<int, float>& p) { 
                                                return p.first == i; }) 
                                != v2.end() }), v1.end());
```

Alternatively sort `v2` on `first` and use a binary search instead. If there is enough memory use an `unordered_set` to sort the `first` of `v2`.

Complete C++03 version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>

struct find_func {
  find_func(int i) : i(i) {}

  int i;
  bool operator()(const std::pair<int, float>& p) {
    return p.first == i;
  }
};

struct remove_func {
  remove_func(std::vector< std::pair<int, float> >* v2) 
  : v2(v2) {}
  std::vector< std::pair<int, float> >* v2;
  bool operator()(int i) {
    return std::find_if(v2->begin(), v2->end(), find_func(i)) != v2->end();
  }
};


int main()
{
  // c++11 here
  std::vector<int> v1 = {5, 3, 2, 4, 7, 8};
  std::vector< std::pair<int, float> > v2 = {{2,8}, {7,10}, {5,0}, {8,9}};
  v1.erase(std::remove_if(v1.begin(), v1.end(), remove_func(&v2)), v1.end());

  // and here
  for(auto x : v1) {
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is O(n^2), would be incredibly slow for millions of items.

Comment: @interjay That's why I added I said: sorting is too expensive and memory is scarce. Sometimes it is just not possible to build a data structure that has memory overhead over a plain array and I also gave the faster solutions.

Comment: @ pmr Thanks, is there any solution without lambda expressions?

Comment: @justik Just wrap transform the lambda in a functor with some closure emulation. I'll hack it up.

Comment: @ pmr Unfortunately I do not have any experience with lambda expressions :-(.